# How can I print prime numbers till 10^8 using Sieve?

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have recently learnt Sieve algorithm and started to play with it to learn how to use the algorithm in problems. I have written the code correctly as I can't find any bugs in  it, but it closes without showing any output. Can't find what's wrong. Help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#define MAX 10000
typedef long long int ll;
using namespace std;
vector <ll> primes;
void sieve(){
    ll MAX = 100000000;
    bool isPrime [MAX];
    for(ll i = 0;i < MAX; ++i)isPrime[i] = true;
    //isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false;
    
    for(ll i=3; i*i <= MAX; i += 2){
        if(isPrime[i]){
            for(ll j = i*i; j <= MAX; j += i){
                isPrime[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    primes.push_back(2);
    for(ll i = 3; i <= MAX; i += 2){
        if(isPrime[i]){
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    for(ll i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){
        cout<<primes[i]<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    sieve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I can't find any bugs in it* **!=** *I have written the code correctly*!

Comment: `bool isPrime [MAX];` -- Why didn't you use `vector` here also?  You used it in other places in your code.

Comment: You haven't said what you've done to figure out where the problem is. Run your program in a debugger and figure out *where* the program is crashing. Knowing where often helps you understand why, or at least narrows the possibilities significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a static array of size `10^8`, which is stored on the stack. This is too large for the stack, and will likely cause a stack overflow.

Instead, use a `vector` that stores the data on the heap, like this:

```
vector<bool> isPrime(MAX+1);
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hK8EaP).

Also, note that you have an off by one error, since you are indexing at the index `MAX`, so the vector should be size `MAX+1`.

Also, you should avoid `using namespace std;`, as well as typedefs like `ll`, they make the code harder to read.

Comment: I have realized the problem. Using vector for both cases now. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use `bitset<100000000>isPrime(0)` to save some memory